# Programmatically update NGPrime Panel style property

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm fairly new to Angular and not sure if I'm doing something wrong in TS or with the PrimeNG component.

I have a simple reactive form and all I'm trying to do is update a style property when submitted.

My panel component loads from HTML including the custom style.

```
<p-panel header="No payment required.." [style]="{margin:'.5rem 2rem'}">
```

In the component TS I use ViewChild to get a handle on it.

```
@ViewChild(Panel, { static: false }) _Panel!: Panel;
```

I'm also trying to hook change detection BUT only because the PrimeNG panel doesn't seem to be updating? I may not need it?

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

During a button click event the _Panel object does update but the UI does not?

```
this._Panel.style = { display: 'none' };
this.cd.detectChanges();
this.cd.markForCheck();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to change whether it is visible or not, I would use the `*ngIf="..."` structural directive, and bind that to a field/property in your component that you can just set to `true` or `false` depending on when you want it to show up in your html :)

```js
@Component({
    ...
    // You don't need to specify changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategry.Default
})
export class MyFormComponent {
    ...

    panelVisible = true;


    myMethodThatChangesPanelVisibility(...) {
        this.panelVisible = false
    }
}
```

```html
<p-panel *ngIf="panelVisible" header="No payment required.." style="margin: .5rem 2rem;">
```

Also, notice that you don't need to use Angular attribute directive binding on the `style` attribute because the expression inside isn't going to change.  So I removed the square brackets and curly brackets from what you had above.

Comment: So that shows my lack of angular knowledge. I thought the *ngif was executed procedurally one time like in a C# application. I guess it's constantly being evaluated somehow? Anyway will make the changes and update the OP with results.

Comment: That's correct @GPGVM, the expression inside the `*ngIf` is re-evaluated on change detection cycles.  The star/asterisk indicates that it is a structural directive, which just means that it is capable of changing the structure of the DOM based on the value of its associated expression.  `NgIf`, `NgFor`, and `NgSwitch` are some examples of built in structural directives, and you can also create your own.

I loved learning Angular, hopefully you'll have the same experience!